# Database Mail Timeout Errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-mail

Getting the following errors periodically from `SP_Send_DBMail`:

> Message
>   The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure.
>   (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2016-08-15T16:46:17).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The operation has timed out.).

What's odd is that the e-mails do get sent out successfully the first time, then due to the default DB Mail Account configuration, the "retry" kicks in and a second e-mail gets sent out so the users are receiving duplicates. In other words, even though we receive the error, the e-mail does actually go out successfully. Then the default account configuration has a Retry Count of 1 which results in a duplicate e-mail to the end-users since the system thinks the e-mail was not sent out successfully (due to the timeout error).

I have tried adjusting the timeout of the DB Mail account to 60 seconds but the issue persists.

The Exchange Server in use does not seem to be under great stress or load to cause this kind of problem.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not following this part, could you explain it? >then due to the default DB Mail Account configuration, the "retry" kicks in and a second e-mail gets sent out

Comment: @SeanGallardy In other words, the error is spurious. Emails are going out, and again a second time when the "retry" kicks in.

Comment: Exactly right, Randolph.

Comment: I was asking about the retry you speak of.. what retry? If it is successfully sent out it is removed from the send queue...

Comment: Sorry, Sean, misunderstood. What I meant in my original post is that even though we receive the error, the e-mail does actually go out successfully. Then the default account configuration has a Retry Count of 1 which results in a duplicate e-mail to the end-users since the system thinks the e-mail was not sent out successfully (due to the timeout error).